# Grails : org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/http/protocol/BasicHttpContext.<init>()V

Tags: rest, grails, rest-client

I'm using grails restclient plugin(':rest:0.7') to consume rest grails rest services.

Here is my code:

```
    def restClient = new RESTClient(ServiceURL)
    def httpResponseDecorator = restClient.get(query: requestMessage)
    pdfData = handleServiceResponse(httpResponseDecorator)
```

But getting the follwing error :

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org/apache/http/protocol/BasicHttpContext.()V   at
>   org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
>     at
>   org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
>     at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
>     at
>   org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
>     at
>   org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736) Caused by: 
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org/apache/http/protocol/BasicHttpContext.()V

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Which version of Grails are you using? And are you using other dependencies/plugins? There is a dependency issue going on, probably two version of httpclient somewhere. Can you create a new application using only that plugin?

Comment: Eric..I'm using grails 1.3.4

Comment: Same one works in my local but when I deploy it in CI using Maven ..it throws that error.

Comment: Please don't use Grails 1.3.4 :) It's a very buggy version, plus 2.x is out for quite some time now. If upgrading is not an option, please try my other suggestions. But please upgrade first.

Comment: And does it work in a new application?

Comment: Erik: Same code works in my local machine and not in CI server...